# Clique factorization

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

I'm reading about Clique factorization in wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_random_field#Clique_factorization

but I'm unable to understand this:

[image]

What is $X_C$ here? Ok I understood that for a value $x$ we multiply the values of functions, where each function correspond to a clique. But what's the input to the function!

Comment: An identical question has also been posted on [stats.SE](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/94233/6633)

Comment: @DilipSarwate I removed it

Answer (score 1):

There is no $X_C$ here and, by definition, $$x_C=(x_v)_{v\in C}.
$$
(This notation is used everyuwhere on the page linked to, and well before the paragraph reproduced in the question.)

Comment: so $x_c$ is a single random variable of a node in the clique or a vector of the random variables of the nodes of the clique?

Comment: Actually, $x_C$ is a set of values indexed by the clique $C$. A single random variable would be $X_v$ with $v$ in $V$, and the set of random variables corresponding to a clique $C$ might be denoted $X_C=(X_v)_{v\in C}$ (although there is no $X_C$ in your question, only $x_C$).